# Cannot redirect to other page with JQuery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using Javascript to redirect a user when he presses `back` button to the previous page. I happen to use JQuery validation plugin on the same page, which validates the form when the button is pressed. It works fine when there is some error in the form, if all the fields of the form are without any error, then it fails to redirect, and same page reloads again.

I tried to cancel the validation using `ignore` on the form, but it is not working.

This is how I am doing it:

```
$("#btnBack").click(function () {
         $("aspnetForm").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
        SaveEmployeeInfo();
    });
```

Here is the form validator:

```
$("#aspnetForm").validate({
        rules: {
            txtGross: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            ddlPay: {
                required: true,
                notEqual: "0"
            },
            ddlTax: {
                required: true,
                notEqual: "0"
            }
        },
        ignore: ".ignore",
    });
```

Here is how I add a method to compare values:

```
`//It is called for each of the required field in the aspnetForm
    $.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function (value, element, param) {
            return this.optional(element) || value !== param;
    }, "Please choose a value!");
```

This is my function that is called for saving employee information:

```
function SaveEmployeeInfo() {
    var employee = GetEmployee();
    defaulted = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "/SaveEmployeeInfo",
        data: $.toJSON({
            saveObject: {
                //all of the employee related information here
            }
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data, st) {
            if (st == 'success' && data.d != null) {
                if (data.d != "undefined") {

                    if (data.d) {
                        window.location = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + "EmployeeInfo.aspx";
                    }
                    else {
                        ShowMessage("Cannot redirect to new employee.");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            if (!String.isNullOrEmpty(msg.responseText))
                ShowMessage(msg.responseText);
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

I want to avoid the call to any sort of validator when my `back` button is pressed, so that I can redirect to the respective page.

Comment: Show the rendered HTML markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the possible `cancel` and `ignore` options, I worked around another way, which was to pass through validator if not avoid it. I did it using a `boolean` variable.

This is how I did it:

```
$("#btnBack").click(function () {
        backClick = true;
        SaveEmployeeFinancials();
    });

$.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function (value, element, param) {
        return (!backClick) && (this.optional(element) || value !== param);
    }, "Please choose a value!");
```

The function will return `false whenever back button is pressed, rendering my redirection to another page.

Answer (score 0):

To skip validation while still using a submit-button, add a class="cancel" to that input.

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
 <input type="submit" class="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/>
```

see http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference look for "Skipping validation on submit"

Comment: I am using `asp.net` button

Comment: @faiz - <asp:Button CssClass="cancel" runat="server" />